# Oracle timestamp comparison is returning data before the time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query :

```
SELECT 
    id, value, time,
    to_char(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:mi:ss') as display_time,
FROM 
    observation
WHERE 
    time  >= to_timestamp('2022-10-26T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') 
    AND time < to_timestamp('2022-10-29T23:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') 
    AND 
ORDER BY 
    time
```

But in result I get data with time starting from 2022-10-25T21:00:00.

The time column is a timestamp. Why is data from an earlier data shown in the result?

The entire query is like:

```
WITH series_ids AS 
(
    SELECT ds.id 
    FROM data_series ds
    INNER JOIN primary_series ps ON ps.id = ds.id
    INNER JOIN station s ON s.id = ps.station_id
    INNER JOIN parameter p ON p.id = ds.parameter_id
    WHERE ps.station_id IN (3230,3231,3232)
      AND p.id IN (474)      
), 
observations AS 
(
    SELECT 
        id, series_id, value, time,
        to_char(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') as display_time
    FROM 
        observation
    WHERE 
        time  >= to_timestamp('2022-10-26T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') AND
        time < to_timestamp('2022-10-29T23:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') AND
        series_id in (SELECT id FROM series_ids)
    ORDER BY 
        time
    FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY
) 
SELECT o.* 
FROM observations o 
INNER JOIN series_ids ds ON ds.id = o.series_id
```

And the result I get is:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0KME.png)

Comment: Does your time have a timezone?

Comment: @TimRoberts no its just a timestamp

Comment: Can you post a reproducible test case?  The DDL to create the table, the DML to insert the data in question, etc?

Comment: Also, can you please share your entire query? Your current query in the question is not valid and we would like to see other conditions that you are using. Are you using `OR` condition in `WHERE` clause somewhere?

Comment: Please try **not** to post [images of data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format tables.

Comment: It should not be possible with this query to get a row of `TIMESTAMP '2022-10-25 21:00:00'`. Is it on purpose by the way that you exclude the last minute of `DATE '2022-10-29'` in your query? When dealing with timestamps and dates, you should not use string literals that you must convert with `TO_DATE` or `TO_TIMESTRING`. Just use date and timestamp literals in the first place (like I am using them in my comment here).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner With  no sample data provided and no context info, having just some code and description on what the issue is it is impossible to be sure what is going on there. So, I suggested to change the where condition to something that works in all contextes - to compare Oracle DATE datatypes instead of TIMESTAMP datatypes. It is not known to me why the resultset of OPs code was wrong.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner My first suggestion was CAST which solved the issue but was too slow (comments) - the other suggestions were just a different ways of puting condition based on DATEs (except one - with fraction in To_Timestamp()).  I don't even know which one was accepted by OP (got info just about slow CAST). There was/is something wrong with TIMESTAMP on either side of Where condition. It could be in the data column or in conversion to timestamp without fractional part. Part of the problem could be in db settings and/or NLS parameters dealing with timestamps.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The answer gives just a few versions of workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your condition ends in seconds - try to change the Where clause comparing dates:

```sql
--  Instead of converting string without fraction to timestamp:
observation.TIME  >= to_timestamp('2022-10-26T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
--  Cast your timestamp as date and compare with To_Date()...
CAST(observation.TIME as DATE)  >= To_Date('2022-10-26 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

OR without Cast letting Oracle to do implicite conversion

```sql
observation.TIME >= To_Date('2022-10-26 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

OR keep your conversion just add fractional part

```sql
observation.TIME >= to_timestamp('2022-10-26T00:00:00.000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

OR the long one converting timestamp to string and string to date

```
To_Date(To_Char(observation.TIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') >= To_Date('2022-10-26 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But the query seems to be noticeably slower now. Can it be improved?

Comment: @AryaPoudel You can try without Cast - it should work. Otherwise it is hard to tell with no insight in yyour context. Just posted an update.

Comment: It doesn't work without Cast. I get the original issue.

Comment: @AryaPoudel Not sure if it helps but there is another update posted

Comment: @AryaPoudel ... and another (last) one...

Comment: @d r: Can you please explain how these methods solve the problem? I don't understand this. The OP says they are getting a row with `timestamp '2022-10-25 21:00:00'` despite the condition `time >= to_timestamp('2022-10-26T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')`. So, why are they getting this row and how do your solutions address this issue?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner UPS, sorry, posted reply under OPs question instead of here.